# Ionic livereload: how to ignore some files?

Tags: ionic-framework, livereload

I have an [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) project and I use external tool for processing Coffee and SCSS. By default livereload in Ionic project watches everything. Where I can change this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This setting is named `watchPatterns` ([source](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/blob/v1_2_6/lib/ionic/serve.js#L58)) and can be changed in `ionic.project` file:

```
{
    ...
    "watchPatterns": ["www/**/*", "!www/lib/**/*", "!www/config.codekit", "!www/**/*.scss", "!www/**/*.coffee"]
}
```

Default value: `["www/**/*", "!www/lib/**/*"]`

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to give an update as the accepted answer does not work for the newer version of Ionic CLI.

For Ionic CLI v3.1.2 & Ionic Framework v1.3.3:

Versions:

```
Ionic CLI : 3.1.2
Ionic Framework : ionic1 1.3.3
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.1.2
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic1 : 1.1.2
```

The "watch pattern" for livereload is not configurable from your project files. You have to change `WATCH_PATTERNS` in the [source code](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/blob/ionic%403.1.2/packages/cli-plugin-ionic1/src/serve/config.ts) itself.

If you've built your Ionic v1 app using the tabs starter app ([doc](https://ionicframework.com/getting-started/)):

Example:`ionic start myApp tabs --type ionic1`

The file you will need to change is in the directory `./myApp/node_modules/@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic1/dist/serve/config.js`

Below is what the file will look like:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const path = require("path");
exports.WATCH_PATTERNS = [
    'scss/**/*',
    'www/**/*',
    '!www/lib/**/*',
    '!www/**/*.map'
];
exports.LOGGER_DIR = '__ion-dev-server';
exports.IONIC_LAB_URL = '/ionic-lab';
exports.DEFAULT_ADDRESS = '0.0.0.0';
exports.DEFAULT_LIVERELOAD_PORT = 35729;
exports.DEFAULT_SERVER_PORT = 8100;
exports.IOS_PLATFORM_PATH = path.join('platforms', 'ios', 'www');
exports.ANDROID_PLATFORM_PATH = path.join('platforms', 'android', 'assets', 'www');
```

From there you can modify the `WATCH_PATTERNS` array to watch or '!' not watch a particular directory or file.

This isn't an ideal solution since the starter app uses the Node Package Manager (NPM) to manage the `@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic1` dependency. If you decide to run this project on another computer or update your node modules, then you would have to re-do the steps above to customize the watch patterns. However, you can fork the source code and tell NPM to use your version instead.

Comment: I use [livereload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/livereload) on port 35729 and want to only livereload two folders  `public` and `assets`, the rest not. is it possible?